# How can I get my wifi to work on my Dell 3521 laptop?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8 in my DELL 3521 laptop and everything is working fine except the wi-fi in Ubuntu.
In win 8 wifi is working well but when I start Ubuntu it does not show any wifi options.

I have tried installing all the drivers required but it's still not working.

```
Atheros Communication Inc. Device [168c:0036] (rev 01)
subsystem: dell device [1028:020c]
```

Comment: this question is answered here take a look.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/379440/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-dell-3521

Answer (score 0):

some times ubuntu initially drivers will not work so,you need to update your drivers to work wifi in ubuntu , so initially connect pc/laptop with "cable" and it automatically detect your internet connection.

After that you can update the drivers then restart the pc , unplug the cable and now you can search your wifi and give password for connection.

Open "Additional Driver" option , it will search the drivers that are required for your PC and Card to support .

After that a list of driver being show , here you can select the driver according to you manufacturing company and Broadcom STA wireless Driver work fine with all cards.

You can find the package --->

```
sudo lspci
sudo dpkg --get-selections
```

Comment: Have tried this but its still not working.Can anyone please provide any alternate solution.

Comment: can you specify which type of error you are getting or trace which package/driver missing using $ sudo lspci