# WiFi not connecting Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.4 (today, to be exact) and I'm unable to connect to my network's WiFi. I've tried every security type just to make sure, and on none of them it has worked. I looked at a few other topics, but none of them solved the problem. Basically, I'll try to make the connection, but then I get a pop-up box asked for the password every few seconds, and then a message saying "Wireless network Disconnected." Please help.

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05) 
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

lspci | grep Wireless:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

cat etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
cat: etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: No such file or directory
```

lspci -nn | grep -i network:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
```

Comment: Please add your PC or laptop's specifications(model, company etc.) and the results of "route -n" , "lspci | grep Wireless" "cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" and "lspci -nn | grep -i network"

Comment: Check the link added in my answer , linked as "this answer" then it will work.

Comment: followed the instructions from that link, wireless is no longer shown on the network manager

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F4
2. Unblock your wifi

> rfkill unblock wlan

1. `Restart your network

> sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: That didn't work, still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the OutPut of-

```
rfkill list all
```

If Wifi is Soft Blocked then use-

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

If its Hard Block try to switch it on physically.

If in a case wifi is not being shown in `rfkill list all` then boot into windows ,switch it on and use use it , after using it for more then a minute give a reboot and boot into Ubuntu and see if its Adapter is detected or not.

Go to Ubuntu-Software-center and clcik on edit and Software Sources  then Additional Drivers as shown below -

[image: here]

If there is no proprietary Driver for wifi , google the term and hopefully then you can install it.

And see also At restart go to **BIOS** and check it must be enabled in BIOS. CHeck the options.

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/379444/192102)  as well.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: WiFi isn't soft or hard blocked, still not working.

Comment: i tried using windows for a bit, then switched back to ubuntu. ubuntu isn't even showing it under the networks list.

Comment: There isn't even an "Additional Drivers" tab for me.

Comment: I found and installed that Broadcom proprietary driver for wifi and still I can't connect