# Should I download the new Hardware support Available for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, 14.10, hardware

This is in relation with this post.

> > [WiFi not working on ubuntu 12.04 dell 3521](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379440/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-dell-3521)

I have done the same steps 8-10 months back and now in Ubuntu Updates it shows New Hardware Support Available.
Should I download the update or not? If I download will the lappy and WI-FI work the same way?
And also can I update from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.xx versions?will it cause any hardware to not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a distribution upgrade in the first instance prior to doing any hardware support updates.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After you have updated the distribution you can then see if the hardware support updates are still available and then opt if you would like to install them or not (self preference?)

If you are not comfortable using command line you could always follow this guide to
[upgrade](http://incisiveradar.com/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-lts-to-14-04-lts/%20%22%22guide)